# Running tsc from the Windows command line

Tags: node.js, windows, typescript

**npm** is installed and is actively being used from IntelliJ IDEA 15

My goal is to generate typings for my TypeScript source code in IntelliJ, but I want to learn using the Windows command line, so I can explicitly specify the command line options to tinker to understand what each option does. I am confused by the various tidbits related to setting this up and using it that I've found by Googling... I'm sure that I'm missing something very basic that those who blog or answer questions assume as common knowledge...

Here's what I've attempted and what I'm seeing...

**Step 1**: install typescript:

`npm install -g typescript`

This results in the following file/directory structure being installed on my system:

```
C:\Users\{my user id}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript
|---bin
|   |--- tsc
|   |--- tscserver
|---lib
|   |--- lib.core.d.ts
|   |--- ...
|   |--- typescriptServices.js
|--- .npmignore
|--- ...
|--- ThirdPartyNoticeText.txt
```

**Step 2**: naively try to run `tsc` directly from the Windows command line:

The examples that I've found by Googling take the form:

***Compile a single file:***

`tsc app.ts`

above example is from http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/typescript-command-line-compiler

This does not work as shown because:

1. The install directory of `tsc` is not on the Windows **`Path`** `C:\Users\{my user id}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin`, obviously this is easily remedied or worked around by changing the Window PATH environmental variable and/or fully qualifying the path to the `tsc` file when entering the command to execute.
2. More significantly the `tsc` file is not a Windows executable... the `#!` Unix script ([shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))) being a dead giveaway.

Inspecting the `tsc` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
require('../lib/tsc.js')
```

**Step 3**: try to run `tsc` from the node command prompt:

`C:\>`**`node`**

`>` **`tsc`**

```
ReferenceError: tsc is not defined
at repl:1:1
at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:252:27)
at bound (domain.js:287:14)
at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:417:12)
at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:210:10)
at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:549:8)
at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:826:14)

^C
```

OK... let's specify the full path to the `tsc` script:

`C:\>`**`node`**

`>` **`C:\Users\{my user id}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc`**

```
...
```

literally the only output is **`...`** when specifying the full path to the `tsc` script... I guess that it wants parameters... but hitting the `tab` key reveals a list of what seem to be **node** commands (not `tsc` commands)... so I've no idea what's going on here...

Now I'm stuck

What environment do I need to install/configure/use to invoke `tsc` (as illustrated by: http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/typescript-command-line-compiler)?

and/or

Is there a tutorial or site that would help me go from a clean Windows system to being able to use the TypeScript compiler from the command line to generate typings for my TypeScript source files?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should not add TypeScript's `bin` folder directly to the Windows `PATH`. As you noticed, the files in that `bin` folder are not directly executable from the command line.

Instead, `npm` creates a `.cmd` script for every configured executable in a globally installed package and puts it in:

```
%APPDATA%\npm
```

Try updating your `PATH` to include this folder, re-open your command line and try running `tsc` again.

Side note: the Node.js installer for Windows by default adds Node and NPM to your Windows path. If you have installed Node.js normally, this should have worked just fine. Anything special about how you have your Node set up?

Comment: for some reason I had to add the expanded version of %APPDATA%\npm to my path for it to start working... I greatly appreciate your help... now I can get back to work... Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

I'll share a couple of gotchas (that got me!) when I installed typescript (I followed https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html) on windows 10. I had earlier setup node by following the instructions at https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows after failing miserably with other approaches.

**Gotcha #1** - Both tsc and tsc.cmd **are** on the path (at %NVM_SYMLINK%) **but** tsc is the bash script. In other words you have to use the command *tsc.cmd* in order to actually invoke the windows version! Just invoking tsc will (in my Powershell terminal) cause it to fall over with weird errors.

**Gotcha #2** - Windows file system locking semantics strikes again!  Because I had been digging into the problem, I had the tsc.cmd file open in an editor - which was locking the file! This causes the correct invocation (tsc.cmd) to *also* fail.. till I closed the editor.

Hope this helps someone..

Answer (score 1):

## Generic solution :

**Analyze**

`typescript\bin\tsc` file content is a unix script but it runs under node

```
#!/usr/bin/env node //<<< this loads node env
require('../lib/tsc.js') //<<< this is plain javascript
```

This file loads node, and execute file : `typescript\lib\tsc.js`

**Solution:**

We want to reproduce the same behavior.
To run .js files with node on Windows :

1. open CMD or PowerShell
2. type: `node /path/to/typescript/lib/tsc.js -options -as-if-i-was-on-linux`
3. press enter

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. I added the full path to system variables. Full path for my case is C:\Users\User\node_modules\typescript\bin

Now tsc transpiles my typescript files.