# How to Run TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Getting Error To Run Typescript

> 'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I have done:

1. create one folder Test
2. cd Test
3. make one file helloword.ts
4. installed typescript by command `npm install -g typescript`
5. tsc helloword.ts

Comment: check if you have typescript sdk path to your path variable under "Environment variables" of windows.

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753867/running-tsc-from-the-windows-command-line) Next time, remember to use the search function if you haven't

Answer (score -1):

You will have to add path of `tsc` in environment variables. On windows it will be `C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\npm`.

Then also add `tsconfig.json` you can do it as:

run `tsc --init` in your directory. This will create a tsconfig.json file in your directory where you can define your configuration.

Here you can find configuration example. [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

Comment: If it can't find `tsc`, and can't see trying to run the same command with arguments working. This looks more like a Windows PATH issue.