# running typescript in visual studio code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run the following class in visual studio code:

```
class Add{
    x: number;
    y: number;

    constructor(x: number, y: number){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }

    Display(){
        console.log(this.x);
        console.log(this.y);
        console.log("Sum = "+ (this.x + this.y));
    }
}

let add = new Add(2,3);
add.Display();
```

I'm following the tutorial from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zNFZjRo9Cc) ,however every time I try to run `tsc --init` I get the following error:

```
tsc : File C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot     
run this script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at 
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ tsc --init
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

And I cannot understand why or how to fix this, help would be apretiated.

P.S: I was able to configure the `launch.json` as stated in the tutorial.

Comment: Did you already try adding the npm path to the Windows' PATH variable? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36754821/5630865

Comment: Have you tried reading the link? Your system currently does not allow to execute powershell scripts because of the execution default execution policy. Set the execution policy to `RemoteSigned` or if that doesn't work try `Unrestricted` If you don't want to change your execution policy (yes, this has security implications) you can use a CMD shell instead of a PS shell in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says:

```
The file C:\Users\Gjestebruker
\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.ps1 is not digitally signed
```

To prevent powershell from calling tsc as tsc.ps1 it has to be called with extension ***.cmd***:

```
tsc.cmd --init
```

Solution 1: Set cmd.exe as default terminal

Solution 2: execute tsc.cmd manually in the powershell terminal

Solution 3: Open powershell as administrator and execute:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```